# node const variable also be changed

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to protect the object and try `const` like below

```
const foo = {'test': 'content'}
foo    // {test: 'content'}

foo['test'] = 'change'
foo    // {test: 'change'}
```

I don't know how to protect the object like dictionary correctly, could anyone help me out?

thanks for your time.

regards.

Comment: As per the _MDN_, `The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It does not mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned`

Comment: @RayonDabre  thanks for your reply, how could I protect the dictionary value?

Answer (score 6):

As Rayon Dabre says, `const` means that the value of the variable cannot be changed. The value of the variable `foo` in your example is unchanged: it is still the same object. That object's *property* changed.

In order to make an object itself unchangeable, you can use `Object.freeze`:

```
var foo = {'test': 'content'};
Object.freeze(foo);
foo.test = 'change';
foo.test
// => "content"
```

Answer (score 1):

See [Object.freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze):

```
const foo = Object.freeze( {'test': 'content'} );
```